# Consolidate MySQL query results

Tags: php, mysql, consolidation

I have a PHP application retrieving data from a MySQL DB. When PHP queries the DB, results are pulled and all the output rows are printed to the screen, but at the top a graph is also printed giving a visualisation of the output rows. As per the following (this is a 24 vertical line bar chart, because MySQL produced 24 rows of output from the query executed on behalf of PHP);

[image: 24 rows of MySQL output]

The problem I face arises if the user runs a query that produces lots of results. The second picture further down is a visual representation of the 150 results MySQL produced when queried on behalf of PHP using different selectable parameters, in the PHP application. I would like have a max number of vertical lines (lets for example sake say 50). When a query produces more than 50 rows we consolidate the MySQL results into just 50 rows for visualisation. I will still be printing all rows below the graph so the user can look at any one result if they so wish. My question is, **What is the optimal way to do this with regard to CPU cycles, without being too difficult to understand and follow in the code?**

[image: 150 rows of MySQL output]

One idea I have had is to tackle this in the PHP application, where I simply divide the number of rows of MySQL output by 50 (again, lets assume easy numbers, rounding is a simple issue to work with in this instance). If MySQL produces 500 rows, 500 divided by 50 is 10, so I use every 10th row to draw a vertical line on the bar chart.

Another idea is to tackle this problem in MySQL. I could perhaps run the MySQL query, then copy the results to a variable, then run a 2nd query against that which selects either every 10th row, or if there is some way to consolidate within MySQL, and then  present a 2nd, smaller data set to PHP.

**Where would be the best place to tackle this issue, and why, and how?**

**Update**:

As requested to explain a little further, Its a quite basic scenario really:

Results looklike the below, each row is an integer value and a time stamp (the bar chart shows value [Y axis] over time period [X axis]);

```
row | value | timestamp 
 1  | 10    | 1234-01-01 10:30
 2  | 10    | 1234-01-01 10:35
 3  | 15    | 1234-01-01 10:40
 4  | 15    | 1234-01-01 10:45
 5  | 10    | 1234-01-01 10:50
```

When MySQL produces 150 rows of output we get a result like the 2nd graph above. I am trying to create a consolidation feature because if the query produces 300 results or example, the lines in the bar chart are all but invisible because they are so thin. That becomes an unnecessary level of visual granularity.

Comment: do you have some sample code/queries that you can post here ? anything that gives an idea about your logic ?

Comment: @Maximus2012 I have updated the question as requested, I hope that is what you where requesting

Comment: what is the query that you are using that generates either of the graphs ?

Comment: @Maximus2012 I fail to see how that matters? I'm trying not to over complicate the question. The graphs are generated by PHP and Javascript, not by MySQL. If it makes that much of a difference, assume the query is `SELECT value, timestamp FROM tblStuff WHERE timestamp>="1234-01-01 00:00" AND timestamp<="1234-01-31 23:55"` So where are selecting all values in a date period

Comment: that is true but isn't the graph getting the data from MySQL. What if its possible to filter at the results at the query level itself so that there would be no issue generating the graph at PHP/JavaScript level ?

Comment: So, you want max X rows and your asking how to run a query to select row number Y from Z number of rows? Is that what you're really wanting or are you wanting the median (or average) from 0 to Y number rows to make your data bar?

Comment: Keep in mind, you'll need to account for rounding when you don't have a modulo 50 number.

Comment: @Maximus2012 I mentioned that in my question `Another idea is to tackle this problem in MySQL....` Also stated in my question is `I will still be printing all rows below the graph so the user can look at any one result if they so wish` - So, I don't want to limit the number of rows I pull from MySQL DB - I want to either know if I should perform a second query against the results set to pick out every 10th row (using the example set out in my question) or do this in the application, looping over the results twice picking out every 10th row to create the graph, then again printing every row...

Comment: oh...ok, that makes sense. So I think what you can do is, run the query only once, but for num_rows > 25 case, use PHP to iterate through the results and put them in an array. Use that array to generate the JavaScript graphs. For num_rows > 25 case you will add only every nth value into the array (while iterating through the MySQL results) where value of n = round (num_rows/25); I hope this makes sense.

Comment: I'm throwing it out there too you guys `Where would be the best place to tackle this issue, and why, and how?` - :) I could simply loop over the result set twice in the application, if so, should I  pick out every 10th row (assuming 500 rows / max 50 vertical pars for clarity) or should I be selecting 10 rows, calculating the median of those 10 rows, and that median becomes one vertical bar, then select the next 10 rows, calculate the median and that median becomes the next vertical bar, and so on, until I have my max 50 vertical bars? Will using the media sacrifice data accuracy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue my self in the PHP application quite simply, rather than making SQL do the work.

In the application I have an array that contains all the MySQL result rows. PHP loops through each Array entry and echo's out the Javascript to display it as a vertical bar on the bar chart.

Inserting this code before that loop solved the issue in a simple and enough manner;

```
$maxbars = 50;
if(count($array_mysql_resutls)>$maxbars) {
    $devision = count($array_mysql_resutls)/$maxbars;
    $resultsarray = Array();
    for($i = 0; $i < $maxbars; $i++) {
        $resultsarray[$i] = $array_mysql_resutls[ceil($devision*$i)];
    }
    $graph_traces = $resultsarray;
}
```

Most importantly, we are rounding up the divided figure (`ceil()`) for an even spread across the results set.